# What's wrong with my foreach php/MySQL code?

Tags: php, foreach

I tried to insert multiple rows from one form using checkboxes, include take values from input box, all of them has the structure:

```
<input id="Valor" type="text" name="Valor[]" value="<?php echo $row2["Valor"];  ?>" />
```

and the checkbox is like:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Pago[]" id="Pago" value="<?php echo $row2["IdSolicitudTarjeta"]; ?>" />
```

But when I'll send the form at 'insertmultiple.php' I use the following code but only shows 2 results. Don't matter how many times I tried show the rest, don't works:

```
foreach($_POST['Pago'] as key => $val) {
$Producto = $_POST['Producto'][$key];
$FormaPago = $_POST['FormaPago'][$key];
$FechaConsignacion = $_POST['FechaConsignacion'][$key];
$Valor = $_POST['Valor'][$key];
$Detalle = $_POST['Detalle'][$key];
$FechaRegistrar = $_POST['FechaRegistrar'][$key];

echo $Pago."&nbsp;--&nbsp;".$FechaConsignacion."&nbsp;--&nbsp;".$Producto."&nbsp;--&nbsp;";
echo $FormaPago."&nbsp;--&nbsp;".$Valor."&nbsp;--&nbsp;".$Detalle."&nbsp;--&nbsp;";
echo $FechaRegistrar."<br>";

}
```

please help! :(

Comment: Where is there mysql code...? Also you've got a lot of xss injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: Can you show us the code of the page that renders the form? Bit hard to understand what's going on prior to this code being executed.

Comment: $AInsertar = "(".$Ider.",".$Producto.",'".$FechaRegistrar."','".$FechaConsignacion."',".$FormaPago.",".$Pagado.",'".$Valor."','".$Detalle."','".$FechaAprobado."'".");";
    $sql = "  INSERT INTO compras(IdCliente,IdProducto,FechaSolicitud,FechaPago,IdFormaPago,RealizoPago,ValorPagado,Detalles,FechaAprobacionPago)
            VALUES ".$AInsertar;
          echo $sql;
      conectar();
    mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
    desconectar();

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing:
 not `key` but `$key`

```
foreach($_POST['Pago'] as $key => $val) {
```

I dont see any SQL code though.

**ADDENDUM**

Hm... it seems like a really messy way to insert things into database. As Cyclone noticed you do not purify your input prior to inserting the date. This is wrong but its a story for another post :p

Besides consider one thing:

Are you sure you want to use

```
$Producto = $_POST['Producto'][$key];
```

and not:

```
$Producto = $_POST['Producto'][$val];
```

You seem to store some id in those checkboxes... otherwise you may have a scenario like:

```
1  [x]
2  [ ]
3  [ ]
4  [x]
```

So I blieve that `$_POST['Pago']` will have only 2 fields 1 and 4... but their key will be 1 and 2 as inactive checkboxes will not have value and will not end-up in the array. I may be wrong though... shame to admit  I do not remember how it works precisely O.o

Comment: You're right, but I don't why when I put $val it doesn't works :( about injections how can I improve or do something? and I don't know what do with my mess of code. I will try to put some value in the unchecked values for see what kind of result apper now. Any idea about what I must do is welcome.

Comment: Hi, sorry for lack of response earlier. As for data validation that is more complicated but the easiest thing to do would be to make sure you use mysql_real_escape_string() function for every field that comes from the form. That will at least remove SQL injection threat. Check this function out on php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved, thanks for your help!!!!!, that's work with the next changes:

```
if(!empty($_POST['Pago'])) {
    $aLista = array_keys($_POST['Pago']);
    $Valor = $_POST['Valor'];
    $Pago = $_POST['Pago'];
    $Producto = $_POST['Producto'];
    $FormaPago = $_POST['FormaPago'];
    $FechaConsignacion = $_POST['FechaConsignacion'];
    $Detalle = $_POST['Detalle'];
    $FechaRegistrar = $_POST['FechaRegistrar'];
foreach($aLista as $key => $val) {
      print "$aLista[$key] => $val";
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;------&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      print "$Valor[$val]";
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;------&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      print "$Producto[$val]";
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;------&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      print "$FormaPago[$val]";
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;------&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      print "$FechaConsignacion[$val]";
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;------&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      print "$Detalle[$val]";
      echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;------&nbsp;&nbsp;";
      print "$FechaRegistrar[$val]";
      echo "<br><hr>";
}
unset($val);
```

}

I guess, now I can Insert that rows without problems,

Comment: Hi, sorry for lack of response earlier.
As for data validation that is more complicated but the easiest thing to do would be to make sure you use mysql_real_escape_string() function for every field that comes from the form. That will at least remove SQL injection threat. Check this function out on http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll read it and I'll put into practice now :D